# Binding Keys to certain commands

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Is it possible to bind a key on the keyboard such as F8 or anything to run a command like to shutdown my computer?

Comment: try autohotkey application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I know is to create a shortcut that does what you want (using scripts and such) and assign it shortcut keys (through Properties > Shortcut tab > Shortcut Key).